# BigChainDB set an infinite amount of assets

Tags: blockchain, bigchaindb

Thanks everyone for the attention.

I'm working on an Application that provides traceability to food, i have to use block-chains.

Each time that an user registers an article that produces, I need to grant him the ability to sell his product as many times as he wants.

I was thinking to use BigchainDB but each time the user sells his product I need to CREATE another asset and TRANSFER it.

Am I misinterpreting some concepts?
Does anyone know a way to achieve this, even with another without having to create another asset?

For this project I have to use block-chains, not necessarily BigchainDB.

EDIT: I've thought to modify the source in order to allow double spending and remove amount management since I need to double spend an assert. However I'm waiting for better suggestions

Thanks a lot to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an asset with large amount

```
{
                "asset": {
                    "data": apples
                },
                "id": "a21d8b1df96d88239c4ae942686fb14d61ad70654504c49d53bff39b53d55ab3",
                "inputs": [
                    {
                        "fulfillment": "cf:4:5GOCGNd_mxZcJxkglXk1b30g8aOEtr25fLkPh7B3dLW1WhjUUxmNUDXmgPPPVdjuxZoxEPCLEKWaqTjaQEfrkTMBb_VBQEc2Nf7bUXpgMtw8iaL7ecbaweGo49aYZs4F",
                        "fulfills": null,
                        "owners_before": [
                            "GNXxib87egiH3guD8Jwegp6xByPoAEVL3px7Niz8WqWC"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "metadata": {
                    "random": 1488859457.5441594
                },
                "operation": "CREATE",
                "outputs": [
                    {
                        "amount": 1000000,
                        "condition": {
                            "details": {
                                "bitmask": 32,
                                "public_key": "GNXxib87egiH3guD8Jwegp6xByPoAEVL3px7Niz8WqWC",
                                "signature": null,
                                "type": "fulfillment",
                                "type_id": 4
                            },
                            "uri": "cc:4:20:5GOCGNd_mxZcJxkglXk1b30g8aOEtr25fLkPh7B3dLU:96"
                        },
                        "public_keys": [
                            "GNXxib87egiH3guD8Jwegp6xByPoAEVL3px7Niz8WqWC"
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "version": "0.10"
            }
```

Comment: This will fail anyway after a while, I've also thought to modify the source in order to remove all the stuff regarding `amount` and `double spending` checks. After all I need to 'double spend' the assert. However I'm waiting for better suggestions